# substring() Function of String Class

Tags: java, string

**I am solving the following question:**  Given a string and a second "word" string, we'll say that the word matches the string if it appears at the front of the string, except its first char does not need to match exactly. On a match, return the front of the string, or otherwise return the empty string. So, so with the string "hippo" the word "hi" returns "hi" and "xip" returns "hip". The word will be at least length 1.

```
startWord("hippo", "hi") → "hi" 

startWord("hippo", "xip") → "hip" 

startWord("hippo", "i") → "h"
```

**My code is as follows:**

```
public String startWord(String str, String word) {
    String front = "";

    if (str.length()>=1 && word.length() == 1) {
        front = Character.toString(str.charAt(0));
    } else {
        if (str.length() >= 1 && str.substring(1, word.length() - 1).equals(word.substring(1)))
        front = str.substring(0, word.length());
    }

    return front;
}
```

`front=str.substring(0,word.length())` is returning "" value. It is a logic question, not a coding question. Trying to work on my logic as an amateur programmer. Thanks for bearing me SO!

Comment: str.substring(0, str.length()); would be the original string

Comment: this logic `if(str.length()>=1 && str.substring(1,word.length()-1).equals(word.substring(1)))` is wrong so `front` never gets a value assigned to it

Comment: learn to debug -- put this     `System.out.println(str.substring(1,word.length()-1));
        System.out.println(word.substring(1));`
 into your code before the `if` statement

Comment: Are you sure you meant to write `word.length()-1` in there?  It doesn't seem right to me.  Read the Javadoc for the `substring`method very carefully, and see if you can figure out why.

Comment: I was doing wrong at "word.length()-1". Thanks for pointing out and thanks to everyone for their precious time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String startWord(String str, String word) {
    if (str.substring(1, word.length()).equals(word.substring(1, word.length()))) {
        return str.substring(0, word.length);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the inputs and outputs that are wrong for you?

Comment: I don't think you should be doing `str.substring(1,word.length()-1)`. Try `str.substring(1,word.length())` instead? I think it's exclusive of the second length.

Comment: There you go! Though I knew that second argument is exclusive, I messed it up a bit. Thankyou!

Comment: If the answer helps you, can you please mark it answered?